# Android Button goes under image

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have some problem with Button and ImageView. 
I have something like that in layout xml:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/startGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pressit"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_running_gradient"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_How_To_Play"
        android:src="@drawable/how_to_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainGame">

       ...
```

On one phone (eq. sony xperia J) when app starts button is under image and relativeLayout and it's ok but on another (eq. LG G2) is above image and layout.
I want first option on all phones. How i can do this ?

Comment: show your full layout

Comment: `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout"` remove the `+`

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainGame">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dfjvb"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_Above="@+id/img_How_To_Play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_How_To_Play"
        android:src="@drawable/photo243"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should not only post code, please explain for OP exactly why Your code is correct....

Comment: please see the OP on http://www.chatup.net78.net/sam.png, Its better because i use relative its look same in all same size of device.